# Xceed DataGrid Error

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, xceed, xceed-datagrid

I just upgraded my project to version 3.0 of the [Extended WPF Toolkit™ Community Edition](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) and now my `DataGrid` shows an error at design time saying:

> The specified view type must derive from ViewBase. Parameter name:
>   TargetViewType

**Is this a new bug in the new version?**

Comment: same here - did you fix it?

Comment: I did, I just don't remember how... Probably rebuilding everything from scratch and restarting VS

Comment: maybe kill xdesproc.exe in task manager works too

Answer (score 1):

I had to add PresentationFramework.Luna (Microsoft DLL).

I'm guessing it was probably there before the update but I had to re-add it. Also had to set it to copy local which shouldn't be necessary but right now I didn't have time to find an alternative way to locate the dll.

[image]

Comment: also had to restart :)